# How do I add this animation class to a modal when a button is clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-5

I want the animation to occur when I click the "x" button on the modal however what currently happens is that the modal closes without it, then upon opening the modal again the animation occurs without clicking anything.

This is my current animation class code:

```
.scale-out-center {
   -webkit-animation: scale-out-center 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.550, 0.085, 0.680, 0.530) both;
    animation: scale-out-center 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.550, 0.085, 0.680, 0.530) both;
    }

@-webkit-keyframes scale-out-center {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
            transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0);
            transform: scale(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@keyframes scale-out-center {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
            transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0);
            transform: scale(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

This is my JavaScript code:

```
<script>
    
    var hideDelay = true;
    document.querySelector('#myModal').addEventListener('hide.bs.modal', function(e) {
        if (hideDelay) {
        document.querySelector('.modal-content').classList.add('scale-out-center');
        hideDelay = false;
        setTimeout(function() {
            document.querySelector('#myModal').modal('hide');
            document.querySelector('.modal-content').classList.remove('scale-out-center');
        }, 5000);
        return false;
        }
        hideDelay = true;
        return true;
    });
        
  
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.cont {
    /* some css here */
}
.cont.scale-out-center {
    animation: myAnimation 1s forwards;
}
```

in javascript when clicking button add element scale-out-center class and animation will be start and as in my code it will be run for 1s. you can setTimeout in js and in 1s close modal. it is simples sollutio.

```
let cont = document.querySelector('.cont')
let btn = document.querySelector('.btn')
btn.addEventListener("click", ()=>{
    // when you add this class to any element animation will be start
    cont.classList.add("scale-out-center ")
})
```